# Custom Splash Screen size - Tabris-JS

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, phonegap, tabris-js

I've searched around questions but I didn't find anything.

I'm new to [Tabris-JS framework](https://tabrisjs.com/), is very powerful and simple but I have some issue with the Splash Screen.

As mentioned in this [commit](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/1051#issuecomment-263847459), in Tabris-JS 2.x there are two theme options: one `light theme`, and the other `dark theme`.
But they both have `margin` around the image.

The result is this (behind the image there is the 'dark gray' background):

[image]

I try to search for the correct `Activity` that is responsable for the Launcher, but I'm not good in Java.

PS: Splash Screen images are all correctly generated, with online tools for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the Tabris.js issue tracker](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/1534), the solution is to theme the android app with a color background on splash, and assume that the splash screen image will be centered.

Since iOS has a more finite number of resolutions this shouldn't be an issue and [the regular Cordova splash screen configuration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#ios-specific-information) applies.